# How do I reassemble IP fragments with Perl's Net::Pcap::Reassemble?

Tags: perl, pcap, hexdump

I am new to Perl and trying to use the [Net::Pcap::Reassemble](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aPcap%3a%3aReassemble) - IP fragment reassembly for [Net::Pcap](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aPcap).  I am trying to reassemble TCP packets and "tie" the packets streams of interest and print the "tied" hex output for that data of interest.  Here is the code below and and the printed output I get.  The printed output is two separate Hex dumps (denoted by "Hex Payload:" string). It is apparent I am not calling Net::Pcap::Reassemble module correctly.  The desire end output that I am trying to achieve is below, taken from the printed output.  Can someone please point me into the right direction in using this module to achieve my desired output?  Thank you.

```
my $user_data;
my $header;
my $packet;   
my $err ='';
my $pcap = Net::Pcap::open_offline("./pcap", \$err) or die "can't open ./pcap...$err\n";
Net::Pcap::loop($pcap, -1, \&process_pkt, '');
Net::Pcap::Reassemble::loop($pcap, -1, \&process_pkt, '');
Net::Pcap::close($pcap);

my $ip;
my $tcp;
my $payload;
sub process_pkt  
{
my ($user_data,$header, $packet) = @_;
$ip = NetPacket::IP->decode(eth_strip($packet));
$tcp = NetPacket::TCP->decode($ip->{data});
$payload = $tcp->{data};

my $hexPayload = hexdump(data => $payload, start_position => 0) if length $payload;
print "Hex Payload:". $hexPayload;

}
```

Output (this is what I currently get, but want to concatenate it together):

```
Hex Payload:  0x0000 : 47 45 54 20 2F 6D 61 63 2F 5F 62 61 73 65 5F 76 : GET./mac/_base_v
0x0010 : 31 2F 73 63 72 69 70 74 2F 6A 71 75 65 72 79 2D : 1/script/jquery-
0x0020 : 31 2E 36 2E 31 2E 6A 73 20 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E : 1.6.1.js.HTTP/1.
0x0030 : 31 0D 0A 48 6F 73 74 3A 20 77 77 77 2E 6D 69 63 : 1..Host:.www.mic
0x0040 : 72 6F 73 6F 66 74 2E 63 6F 6D 0D 0A 55 73 65 72 : rosoft.com..User
0x0050 : 2D 41 67 65 6E 74 3A 20 4D 6F 7A 69 6C 6C 61 2F : -Agent:.Mozilla/
0x0060 : 35 2E 30 20 28 4D 61 63 69 6E 74 6F 73 68 3B 20 : 5.0.(Macintosh;.
0x0070 : 49 6E 74 65 6C 20 4D 61 63 20 4F 53 20 58 20 31 : Intel.Mac.OS.X.1
0x0080 : 30 2E 36 3B 20 72 76 3A 31 33 2E 30 29 20 47 65 : 0.6;.rv:13.0).Ge
0x0090 : 63 6B 6F 2F 32 30 31 30 30 31 30 31 20 46 69 72 : cko/20100101.Fir
0x00A0 : 65 66 6F 78 2F 31 33 2E 30 0D 0A 41 63 63 65 70 : efox/13.0..Accep
0x00B0 : 74 3A 20 2A 2F 2A 0D 0A 41 63 63 65 70 74 2D 4C : t:.*/*..Accept-L
0x00C0 : 61 6E 67 75 61 67 65 3A 20 65 6E 2D 75 73 2C 65 : anguage:.en-us,e
0x00D0 : 6E 3B 71 3D 30 2E 35 0D 0A 41 63 63 65 70 74 2D : n;q=0.5..Accept-
0x00E0 : 45 6E 63 6F 64 69 6E 67 3A 20 67 7A 69 70 2C 20 : Encoding:.gzip,.
0x00F0 : 64 65 66 6C 61 74 65 0D 0A 52 65 66 65 72 65 72 : deflate..Referer
0x0100 : 3A 20 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 77 77 77 2E 6D 69 63 : :.http://www.mic
0x0110 : 72 6F 73 6F 66 74 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 6D 61 63 2F 72 : rosoft.com/mac/r
0x0120 : 65 6D 6F 74 65 2D 64 65 73 6B 74 6F 70 2D 63 6C : emote-desktop-cl
0x0130 : 69 65 6E 74 0D 0A 44 4E 54 3A 20 31 0D 0A 43 6F : ient..DNT:.1..Co
0x0140 : 6E 6E 65 63 74 69 6F 6E 3A 20 6B 65 65 70 2D 61 : nnection:.keep-a
0x0150 : 6C 69 76 65 0D 0A 0D 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : live............
Hex Payload:  0x0000 : 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31 20 32 30 30 20 4F 4B 0D : HTTP/1.1.200.OK.
0x0010 : 0A 43 61 63 68 65 2D 43 6F 6E 74 72 6F 6C 3A 20 : .Cache-Control:.
0x0020 : 6D 61 78 2D 61 67 65 3D 39 30 30 0D 0A 43 6F 6E : max-age=900..Con
0x0030 : 74 65 6E 74 2D 54 79 70 65 3A 20 61 70 70 6C 69 : tent-Type:.appli
0x0040 : 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 2F 78 2D 6A 61 76 61 73 63 72 : cation/x-javascr
0x0050 : 69 70 74 0D 0A 43 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 2D 45 6E 63 : ipt..Content-Enc
0x0060 : 6F 64 69 6E 67 3A 20 67 7A 69 70 0D 0A 4C 61 73 : oding:.gzip..Las
0x0070 : 74 2D 4D 6F 64 69 66 69 65 64 3A 20 57 65 64 2C : t-Modified:.Wed,
0x0080 : 20 30 38 20 4A 75 6E 20 32 30 31 31 20 31 38 3A : .08.Jun.2011.18:
0x0090 : 34 35 3A 34 39 20 47 4D 54 0D 0A 41 63 63 65 70 : 45:49.GMT..Accep
```

Desired output (the above tied/concatenated together):

```
Hex Payload:  0x0000 : 47 45 54 20 2F 6D 61 63 2F 5F 62 61 73 65 5F 76 : GET./mac/_base_v
0x0010 : 31 2F 73 63 72 69 70 74 2F 6A 71 75 65 72 79 2D : 1/script/jquery-
0x0020 : 31 2E 36 2E 31 2E 6A 73 20 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E : 1.6.1.js.HTTP/1.
0x0030 : 31 0D 0A 48 6F 73 74 3A 20 77 77 77 2E 6D 69 63 : 1..Host:.www.mic
0x0040 : 72 6F 73 6F 66 74 2E 63 6F 6D 0D 0A 55 73 65 72 : rosoft.com..User
0x0050 : 2D 41 67 65 6E 74 3A 20 4D 6F 7A 69 6C 6C 61 2F : -Agent:.Mozilla/
0x0060 : 35 2E 30 20 28 4D 61 63 69 6E 74 6F 73 68 3B 20 : 5.0.(Macintosh;.
0x0070 : 49 6E 74 65 6C 20 4D 61 63 20 4F 53 20 58 20 31 : Intel.Mac.OS.X.1
0x0080 : 30 2E 36 3B 20 72 76 3A 31 33 2E 30 29 20 47 65 : 0.6;.rv:13.0).Ge
0x0090 : 63 6B 6F 2F 32 30 31 30 30 31 30 31 20 46 69 72 : cko/20100101.Fir
0x00A0 : 65 66 6F 78 2F 31 33 2E 30 0D 0A 41 63 63 65 70 : efox/13.0..Accep
0x00B0 : 74 3A 20 2A 2F 2A 0D 0A 41 63 63 65 70 74 2D 4C : t:.*/*..Accept-L
0x00C0 : 61 6E 67 75 61 67 65 3A 20 65 6E 2D 75 73 2C 65 : anguage:.en-us,e
0x00D0 : 6E 3B 71 3D 30 2E 35 0D 0A 41 63 63 65 70 74 2D : n;q=0.5..Accept-
0x00E0 : 45 6E 63 6F 64 69 6E 67 3A 20 67 7A 69 70 2C 20 : Encoding:.gzip,.
0x00F0 : 64 65 66 6C 61 74 65 0D 0A 52 65 66 65 72 65 72 : deflate..Referer
0x0100 : 3A 20 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 77 77 77 2E 6D 69 63 : :.http://www.mic
0x0110 : 72 6F 73 6F 66 74 2E 63 6F 6D 2F 6D 61 63 2F 72 : rosoft.com/mac/r
0x0120 : 65 6D 6F 74 65 2D 64 65 73 6B 74 6F 70 2D 63 6C : emote-desktop-cl
0x0130 : 69 65 6E 74 0D 0A 44 4E 54 3A 20 31 0D 0A 43 6F : ient..DNT:.1..Co
0x0140 : 6E 6E 65 63 74 69 6F 6E 3A 20 6B 65 65 70 2D 61 : nnection:.keep-a
0x0150 : 6C 69 76 65 0D 0A 0D 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 : live............
0x0160 : 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31 20 32 30 30 20 4F 4B 0D : HTTP/1.1.200.OK.
0x0170 : 0A 43 61 63 68 65 2D 43 6F 6E 74 72 6F 6C 3A 20 : .Cache-Control:.
0x0180 : 6D 61 78 2D 61 67 65 3D 39 30 30 0D 0A 43 6F 6E : max-age=900..Con
0x0190 : 74 65 6E 74 2D 54 79 70 65 3A 20 61 70 70 6C 69 : tent-Type:.appli
0x0200 : 63 61 74 69 6F 6E 2F 78 2D 6A 61 76 61 73 63 72 : cation/x-javascr
0x0210 : 69 70 74 0D 0A 43 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 2D 45 6E 63 : ipt..Content-Enc
0x0220 : 6F 64 69 6E 67 3A 20 67 7A 69 70 0D 0A 4C 61 73 : oding:.gzip..Las
0x0230 : 74 2D 4D 6F 64 69 66 69 65 64 3A 20 57 65 64 2C : t-Modified:.Wed,
0x0240 : 20 30 38 20 4A 75 6E 20 32 30 31 31 20 31 38 3A : .08.Jun.2011.18:
0x0250 : 34 35 3A 34 39 20 47 4D 54 0D 0A 41 63 63 65 70 : 45:49.GMT..Accep
```

Comment: hexdump is nice, but since you're using perl, Data::Dump / Data::Dumper output would be nicer :)

Comment: Thx for the reply.  I need to be able to see the whole packet session (i.e. tie all packets together for a given file download requests and be able to evaluate the payload).  If I emply Data::Dumper with the hexdump output coupled with Net::PCAP etc. I am still stuck with how can I tie all the hex payload data together for given packets of interest?  Can you please elaborate on your suggestion with using Data::Dumper?  Thx

Comment: Net::Pcap::Reassemble is (probably) assembling fragmented IP packets as it is supposed to do; what you describe is reassembling TCP streams;  also, the two packets in your example are from opposite directions, one is a HTTP request, the other is a reply; you might not want to combine them into one.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to reassemble a network session, not a fragmented network packet.  You should be using the module 'Net::Analysis'.  It can, with some effort on your part, reassemble a complete network session.  You will soon learn to hate pipe-lining.